# split the video in several part using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I want to write a small program with help of ffmpeg. I want to process a video by cut the video into several parts, left part, right part...etc.
How can I do it using ffmpeg? By the way, are there any documentation explain the API of the ffmpeg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ffmpeg [crop filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#crop) to "cut" part of the video and save it to a file. The following example saves the bottom right quarter of the input image (taken from the link):

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -vf crop=in_w/2:in_h/2:in_w/2:in_h/2 output.avi
```

See [doc/examples/filtering.c](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/filtering.c) for an example of how to do it in C.

Comment: thank you very much first, but how can I use the library to do that, not CLI?I mean in a C code, how can I invoke it?

Comment: I added a reference to a coding example to the post.